# Php Zip Archive Checkbox Array

Tags: php

I am trying to do up a form where user get to select the PDF brochures they want and it will be zipped up as a filename "Brochures.zip" for them to download.

I am having problem to get this up. Can anybody highlight where went wrong? Thanks!

form :

```
<label><input type="checkbox" name="brochure[]" value="file1">file1</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="brochure[]" value="file2">file2</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="brochure[]" value="file3">file3</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="brochure[]" value="file4">file4</label>
```

download.php

```
$brochure = $_POST['brochure'] ;
$send = true;
if($send) {
    $zip = new ZipArchive();
    $res = $zip->open('download.zip', ZipArchive::CREATE);
    if ($res === TRUE) {
        foreach ($brochure as $file => $val) {
            $filename = '../pdf/' . $val . '.pdf';
            $zip->addFile($filename);
        }
        $zip->close();

        header('Content-type: application/zip');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="download.zip"');
        readfile('download.zip');

    }else {
        echo 'failed';
    }
```

Comment: @Jack, it doesn't add the selected files to the zip archive

Comment: I have checked your code and its working perfectly as expected. download.zip file is being created when i submit the form.

Comment: @kamal yupp it is created, but no files are added to the zip archive. I have did what Jack had advise but no error codes are shown. Hmm :x

Comment: Make sure that u have right file name at pdf folder located at one directory up...

Answer (score 0):

If the files are not added to the archive, you could add a simple check:

```
if (!file_exists($filename)) { die("Cannot find $filename"); }
```

You could also up the error reporting:

```
error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
```

And then `exit;` right after `$zip->close();`. `$zip->addFile()` should return `false` if anything went wrong, so hopefully it will also show some warnings / errors.

You could also try `addFromString()` with `file_get_contents()` instead to see if that helps. My guess is that the relative path with `..` in it throws off the Zip extension.

Comment: Yupp I did. It did not reflect the filename. Thus I was wondering what went wrong with the coding.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the directory structure..

- PDF

  -- file1.pdf

  -- file2.pdf

  -- file3.pdf
- zip

  -- create.php

  -- download.php

Below is the code same as yours...

create.php

```
<form action="download.php" method="post">
<label><input type="checkbox" name="brochure[]" value="file1">file1</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="brochure[]" value="file2">file2</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="brochure[]" value="file3">file3</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="brochure[]" value="file4">file4</label>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

download.php is the same as above your code. Make sure that you have right directory structure. As I said i tried your code and its working as expected creating download.zip file with selected files like file1.pdf, file2.pdf, etc...

Comment: Yupp. That's exactly what I did. PDF files are in PDF folder. download.php is in a folder named data. download.zip is created, but empty with no files. Could it be the checkbox array I'm calling is wrong?

Comment: I don't think so cause i can see files in download.zip file. I am not sure what's the actual reason without having to look at your code.

Answer (score 0):

I manage to fix the problem by using the script [here](http://www.9lessons.info/2012/06/creating-zip-file-with-php.html). Also, I realized I need to set the folder with permission to 757 before it can generate the zip file.